# Where is stored in memory the reference to current object?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compilation

I have a simple question. I know that after compile a program when I call a function a call stack is generated with the arguments, space for local vars, return point and the registers that i'm charged.

But in object-oriented language like c++, where the compiler stores the reference to the current object? `object->instanceMethod()` will store the object pointer like an argument in the call stack?

I know the question is generalist and thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, when a member function is called the pointer to the instance on which it will operate (i.e. what will be `this` inside the function) is implicitly passed alongside the other function arguments/parameters.  Actually, different systems use different conventions, so some number of such parameters could be packed into registers and never placed on the stack (this tends to be faster), but your conception is basically sound.

Answer (score 3):

It's implementation-defined but in practice you will find that most (all?) C++ compilers generate code which passes the `this` pointer as a hidden first argument to the function, so you can access it without explicitely specifiying it in the method signature.

Comment: Some compilers may use a special calling convention. For instance the `__thiscall` convention of Visual C++ is to pass the `this` pointer into the ECX register for 32-bit builds.

Comment: Yes, but that's just an implementation detail of how arguments are passed (on the stack versus using registers). All I wrote is that it's passed as an implicit first argument, which is independant of the calling convention. :-)